# Highest values among corresponding field in oracle

Tags: datatable, max, field, multiple-columns, highest

I have two supplier_type (Direct and Indirect) for one supply code. I want to produce a new column `supplier_type` based on `supplier_Name` for one `supply_code` like

Example:

- If `supply_Name` is Apple,Dell,Hp,Lenovo then `supply_type` as Direct
- If `supply_Name` is laptops,mouse,keyboard then indirect for the `supplier_code` 2023.

Here I want to get the highest value of `supplier_type` by counting how many `supplier_type` are Direct and indirect for each `supplier_code`.

Sample table:

```
S_CODE  S_NAME  S_TYPE  
----------------------
2023.   APPLE.  DIRECT
2023.   DELL.   DIRECT
2023.   MOUSE.  INDIRECT
2023.   LENOVO. DIRECT
2022.   DELL.   DIRECT
2022.   LAPTOP. INDIRECT
2022.   MOUSE.  INDIRECT
```

Here, we have supplier code 2023 and 2022

For supplier code 2023 we have 3 direct and 1 indirect, so we need to pass the value as Direct in `supplier_type` column

And for supplier code 2022 we have 1 direct and 2 indirect, so we need to pass the value as Indirect in `supplier_type` column.

```
select supplier_type 
from supplier_table 
where count_of_supplier in (select distinct max(count_of_supplier) 
                            from supplier table 
                            group by supplier_type) 
order by supplier_code
```